# Creating Calculator in C#, need help implementing math logic/something else

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        bool plus;
        bool minus;
        bool multiply;
        bool divide;

        private void button0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "0";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "1";
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "2";
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "3";
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "4";
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "5";
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "6";
        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "7";
        }

        private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "8";
        }

        private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "9";
        }

        private void buttonPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "")
                return;
            else
            {
                plus = true;
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " + ";
            }
        }

        private void buttonDivide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "")
                return;
            else
            {
                divide = true;
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " / ";
            }
        }

        private void buttonMinus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "")
                return;
            else
            {
                minus = true;
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " - ";
            }
        }

        private void buttonMultiply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "")
                return;
            else
            {
                multiply = true;
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " * ";
            }
        }

        private void buttonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        private void buttonEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (plus)
            {

            }

            if (minus)
            {

            }

            if (multiply)
            {

            }

            if (divide)
            {

            }
        }


    }
}
```

The part I am stuck on, is after I press a math button (+,-,/,*). I only want one character to show in the textbox, unless I press another number.

Example: Right now, this is what happens:
87 + + + + + + + +

I want 87 +
and I want it where I can add another if the user adds another number, so like 87 + 87 + etc.

Also, I need a little direction when it comes to adding the math logic.

I was thinking of somehow storing whatever was in the string prior to a math sign in a variable, then doing the same for the numbers proceeding the math sign. Is that fine or is there an easier/less complicated way to accomplish this?

Comment: This sounds like homework.  You should add the homework tag to your questions if they are homework.

Comment: It's not. I am teaching myself.

Comment: I'm his friend and I can vouch for him in regards to this not being homework.

Comment: Ah, my apologies.  Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the +-*\ situation.. I would suggest a Boolean property like lastCharIsSymbol. Whenever you click a number set it equal to false, and when you click a symbol set it equal to true. Then you can add an if statement in your symbol click events to only add the symbol IF lastCharIsSymbol = false.

```
public Boolean lastCharIsSymbol {get;set;}

private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "9";
    lastCharIsSymbol = false;
}

private void buttonPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == "" || lastCharIsSymbol)
        return;
    else
    {
        plus = true;
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " + ";
        lastCharIsSymbol = true;
    }
}
```

If you would rather not do this, you can also change up your if statement to just take a substring of whatever is in the textbox and find out what the last character is.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that a good approach to your calculator, rather than testing strings and so on, is to use [states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) to determine the "moment" of your calculator.
Let's think about some states:

- **NotInitialized**: only accepts numbers. When the first digit is given, calculator goes to **Receiving**
- **Receiving**: more digits will be concatenated. Any operator will take the calculator to **NextNumber**
- **NextNumber**: only accepts numbers. When the first digit is given, calculator goes to **Receiving**

And then it goes. Try to figure out what are the states that describe the operation of your calculator.

Comment: Doesn't states seem a bit advanced for someone who is still a relative rookie to programming?

Comment: It can clean things up and make it more readable.  I think holding state is an excellent beginner tool!

Comment: Bill, I believe that state is a natural way of thinking about "things that change", even outside the programming world. Also, teachers usually talk about states to freshmen. If you can't follow this approach, let's try another one, there's no problem =)

Comment: Theres no problem. I just haven't really gotten that far in terms of reading yet. I've been at this for almost 4 years now. But being naive. I jumped straight into XNA without really making sure I understood C#/programming in general. So I have SOME experience, just not to the point where I want to be. So I'm taking a step back/going through all the basics of C# itself before I jump back into XNA.

Comment: That's good, just be sure to jump back to some concepts as well. Try to design a solution prior to coding it. Grab a paper and draw the states of your calculator and which events make the state change.

Answer (score 0):

While you can simply write to a string and then parse it from there when the user presses equals, it might be more beneficial to create a collection of what they enter.  Then, when the user enters something you can make sure that they don't put 2 numbers next to eachother or 2 operators next to eachother. For example, you have do deal with negative numbers as well as multi-digit numbers even if you're only doing a simple calculator. I'd make it such that numbers can be entered and upon pressing an operator, it commits the number and the operator to the list. If the operator is the equals key, you iterate the list and perform the calculation.

An example would be the current windows calculator. You'll notice that there's 2 textboxes. One gives the current working number while the other gives the overall equation.

Here's an example. There are better ways to go about this but for simplicity's sake in pointing you in a decent direction this should work.

```
    List<object> calculatorChain = new List<object>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the button press for the minus key
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The originating object</param>
    /// <param name="e">Event arguments</param>
    private void buttonMinus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CommitOperand(textBox1.Text, "-");
        textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Commits the current working number to the calculator chain with a given operator
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="operand">The current working number to add</param>
    /// <param name="operation">The operation to perform</param>
    private void CommitOperand(string operand, string operation)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(operand) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(operation))
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            decimal number;
            if (decimal.TryParse(operand, out number))
            {
                calculatorChain.Add(number);
                calculatorChain.Add(operation);
            }
        }
    }
```